# android Nullpointerexception when load listview

Tags: android

i have an android code, but always `error : Nullpointerexception` when load this `listview`and `adapter`, 
this is `loadlist` method in `fragment` :

loadlist is line 285

```
private void loadList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        resultList = getListData();

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pbb_data_op_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new LogListAdapter(rootView.getContext(), createDummyData()));

    }
```

and this create dummy just a dummy for listview

```
public List<ACTIVITY_LOG> createDummyData() {
        List<ACTIVITY_LOG> logs = new ArrayList<ACTIVITY_LOG>();

        ACTIVITY_LOG log = new ACTIVITY_LOG();
        log.setmMenu(MenuString.MENU_PBB);
        log.setmSubMenu("Verifying");
        log.setmAktifitas("Melakukan Insert Data");
        log.setmDate(new Date());

        ACTIVITY_LOG log2 = new ACTIVITY_LOG();
        log2.setmMenu(MenuString.MENU_X);
        log2.setmSubMenu("DATA OP");
        log2.setmAktifitas("Melakukan Insert Data sofie");
        log2.setmDate(new Date());

        logs.add(log);
        logs.add(log2);


        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            int counter = 1200;

            ACTIVITY_LOG log3 = new ACTIVITY_LOG();
            log3.setmMenu(MenuString.MENU_X);
            log3.setmSubMenu("DATA OBJEK PAJAK");
            log3.setmAktifitas("Melakukan Update Data "
                    + (counter + i) + ".0");
            log3.setmDate(new Date());

            logs.add(log3);
        }


        return logs;
    }
```

this is log list activity :

```
public class LogListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context thisContext;
    private List<ACTIVITY_LOG> thisListData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public LogListAdapter(Context context, List listData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        thisContext = context;
        thisListData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(thisContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return thisListData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return thisListData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.log_list_item_layout,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.gambarMenuView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.gambar_menu);
            holder.subMenuView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.sub_menu_nama);
            holder.aktifitasView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.aktifitas_nama);

            holder.tanggalView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.aktifitas_tanggal);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        int menuId = thisListData.get(position).getmMenu();

        holder.gambarMenuView.setImageResource(MenuString.getMenuImage(menuId));
        holder.subMenuView.setText(thisListData.get(position).getmSubMenu());
        holder.aktifitasView
                .setText(thisListData.get(position).getmAktifitas());
        holder.tanggalView
                .setText(thisListData.get(position).getmDate() != null ? thisListData
                        .get(position).getmDate().toString()
                        : "");
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView gambarMenuView;
        TextView subMenuView;
        TextView aktifitasView;
        TextView tanggalView;

    }

}
```

this is logcat :

```
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at com.imotax.fragments.pbb.PBBDataOPFormLSPOPFragment.loadList(PBBDataOPFormLSPOPFragment.java:285)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at com.imotax.fragments.pbb.PBBDataOPFormLSPOPFragment.access$0(PBBDataOPFormLSPOPFragment.java:278)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at com.imotax.fragments.pbb.PBBDataOPFormLSPOPFragment$1.onItemSelected(PBBDataOPFormLSPOPFragment.java:141)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
09-02 16:20:08.646: E/AndroidRuntime(14848):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i dont know why, but if i create this in other activity not in loadlist method like this problem, it work.
is there reason or solve?

Comment: where did you got the null pointer exception? post the line number along with logcat.

Comment: where is the nullpointer coming from? there should be a line number in the logcat to show you where in the code the null pointer is being caused

Comment: can you please post your logcat

Comment: using `rootView.getContext()` should be enough

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks, i've updated it, :)

Comment: @yozawiratama post `PBBDataOPFormLSPOPFragment.java` and what is line 285

Comment: @yozawiratama load list function called on onCreateView() method??

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely put the Stack Trace of the exception so we could see where is the error.

In the mean time you have an error while inflating the list item in getView method.
change from:

```
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.log_list_item_layout, null);
```

to:

```
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.log_list_item_layout, parent, false);
```

EDIT:
which line is 285 in the loadList method? 
and you might consider using getActivity() instead of rootView.getContext().getApplicationContext() since you are loading the list inside fragment